# React passing onChange event down to child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';

import Form from './form.jsx';

import axios from 'axios';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      location: ''
    };
  }
  getSearchedValue(e) {
    this.setState({ location: e.target.value });
  }
  searchNearPlaces (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log(this.getSearchedValue());

    const clientID = 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
          clientSecret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
          version = 'v=20140806';
    let location = this.state.location,
        url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?client_id=' + clientID + '&client_secret=' + clientSecret + '&near=' + location + '&' + version;

    axios.get(url)
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
  render () {
    return (
        <section className="main">
            <Form action={this.searchNearPlaces.bind(this)} value={this.getSearchedValue.bind(this)} />
        </section>
    );
  }
}

render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

and a form component:

```
import React from 'react';

class Form extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <form className="form-group">
                <input type="text" onChange={this.props.value} />
                <input onClick={this.props.action} type="submit" />
            </form>
        );
    }
}

export default Form;
```

the moment I click on submit after having typed 'london' for example I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined
```

referring to:

```
  getSearchedValue(e) {
    this.setState({ location: e.target.value });
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Likely because of this line in your code:

```
console.log(this.getSearchedValue());
```

Since you are not passing anything to it, `e` is undefined.